# Django CMS 2.4.3 installation - fresh instal does not work

Tags: django-cms, failed-installation

I am new to python and django and I tried to install Django CMS 2.4.3. I work with python 2.7.6 and Django 1.6.

I did everything as I was told in documentation however "ImportError: No module named cms.plugins.text" occured after syncdb (when I delete cms.plugins.text from INSTALLED_APPS import error shows the last position from installed_apps e.g. cms.plugins.teaser).

Tried to google it and all I found was this: [Django CMS fails to syncdb or migrate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026728/django-cms-fails-to-syncdb-or-migrate)

Didn't help. Any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an error that is not caused by the django cms. Try to open python in the interactive mode and to import your plugin:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Oct  1 2012, 22:07:21) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cms.plugins.text
```

This should not throw any error. If it does, the plugin is not installed or not on your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: You are right - plugin were not installed... Thank you very much! It seems you saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the name has changed from "cms.plugins.text" to "djangocms_text_ckeditor".